# Why is solution 2 correct?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

**Question:**

> N(t) is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$, let $S_n$ denotes the time when the $n$-th event happens. Try to calculate $E(S_4|N(1)=2)$.

**Solution 1:**

> Let $F(x|N(1)=2)$ be the CDF.
> $$F(x|N(1)=2)=Pr(S_4 \leq x|N(1)=2)=\frac{Pr(N(x)-N(1) \geq 2,N(1)=2)}{Pr(N(1)=2)}=Pr(N(x)-N(1) \geq 2)$$
> It's easy to get:
> $$Pr(N(x)-N(1) \geq 2)=1-e^{\lambda(x-1)}-\lambda(x-1)e^{-\lambda(x-1)}$$
> So
> $$ F(x|N(1)=2)=\left\{
> \begin{aligned}
> &0  &x \leq 1 \\
> &1-e^{\lambda(x-1)}-\lambda(x-1)e^{-\lambda(x-1)}  &x>1 \\
> \end{aligned}
> \right.
> $$
> Thus:
> $$E(S_4|N(1)=2)=\int_{0}^{\infty}1-F(x|N(1)=2)dx=1+\frac{2}{\lambda} $$

Solution 1 is correct and easy to understand. But there is a solution 2 which i can not understand.

**Solution 2:**

> What we need to calculate is $E(S_4|N(1)=2)$, it's a conditional expectation. The time that the first and second events need equals 1. As we know, the time interval between events is exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, whose mean queals $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. After the first and second events, There are two events need to happen, thus the total expected time is $1+\frac{2}{\lambda}$

**My question:**

I am wondering if the logic of solution 2 is right? Because the time that the first and second events need is less than or equals 1.

The result is right but i am not sure if it's a conincidence.

Answer (score 2):

The condition $N(1)=2$ means that *exactly* two events have occurred *before* time $1$.

Thus this condition specifies that a *third* event has not occurred by time $1$. (And, of course, neither the forth.)

The **memoryless** property of exponential distributions that the expected wait duration until the next event after *any* given time point will be $1/\lambda$.

(It does not matter *when* the second event has occurred before the given time point, only that it *has* occurred while the third has *not* occurred by then.)

Therefore the expected time for the occurrence of the third and forth event when given that the third does not occur before time $1$, will be the $1$ plus the expected wait duration for two events.$$\mathsf E(S_4\mid N(1)=2)=1+\mathsf E(S_2)$$

---

In general, where $m>n$ are integer event counts and $t$ a positive real time mark, $$\mathsf E(S_n\mid N(m)=t)~{=t+\mathsf E(S_{n-m})\\=t+(n-m)/\lambda}$$

Comment: Thank you a lot! You deepened my understanding of memorylessness.

Comment: There's a problem, according to [ Inspection paradox],(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory). I think the interval between the secont event and the third event is not exponential distribution, so we can not use memoryless property.

Comment: No, @Jxb . A Renewal Process is a generalisation of Poisson Process but with non-exponential wait times. However, this is just a Poisson Process , so it has exponentially distributed wait times.